# Browser adds close tag before page fully loaded

Tags: c#, html, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I am trying to create a div dynamically that holds 3 other divs inside, however, the browser is automatically adding the close tag before blazor ends injecting the code which is very annoying. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

```
int i = 1;

foreach (itemModel item in itemList)
{
  if (i == 1)
  {
    @((MarkupString)"<div>");
  }

  <div></div>

  if (i == 3)
  {
    @((MarkupString)"</div>");
    i = 0;
  }

  i++;
}
```

desired output

```
<div> <- Parent
  <div></div> <- Child
  <div></div> <- Child
  <div></div> <- Child
</div>
```

actual output

```
  <div></div> <- Parent
  <div></div> <- Child
  <div></div> <- Child
  <div></div> <- Child
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you mean "actual output" - HTML output of the server (as seen on network tab/source) or as browser shows in "inspect element"?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what I mean by "actual output" is how the browser shows the elements

Comment: Your really should be looking at raw HTML to know if code renders something that you don't expect or it's browser fixing up HTML you like. Side note: I'd simply use nested loop and render begin/end `div` normally (`for (all; i+=3){ <div> for (0; i <3; i++) { render(start+i)} </div>}`...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I used your idea, made a few changes and it worked. You can post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution if you want. Thanks!

Comment: I see you have resolved this - just wanted to explain that Blazor's MarkupString will not let you create unclosed elements - that is why you were seeing that behaviour.

Comment: @MisterMagoo yes I noticed that, but it's annoying because in some situations it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're overcomplicating it...

```
<div> <!-- parent -->
@foreach (itemModel item in itemList)
{
   <div></div><!-- child -->
}
</div>
```

Unless of course the question is incomplete

Comment: The question says explicitly that each parent must hold 3 children

Comment: Your question was unclear about what the nature of the problem and the example compounded this. It should probably have been "I have a list of items with a varying number of elements, and I need to wrap every three elements with an outer `div` tag. The example could be
```
<div>
 <div>child<div/> 
 <div>child<div/> 
 <div>child<div/> 
</div>
<div>
 <div>child<div/> 
 <div>child<div/> 
 <div>child<div/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple code is good code.

Instead of writing MarkupString, tell the compiler when to add the tags. MarkupString should be reserved for rendering text that contain markup (usually unknown markup from a database)

```
@foreach (var item in new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" })
{
    int i = 0;
    <div>
        <p>parent @item</p>
        @while (i < 3) {
            <div><p>child @i</p></div>
            i++;
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: This is very different from what I was looking for, however, I found a simple code solution that fits my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It send many steps to add elements , not joining into a single HTML string

The logic of the MarketString is more like

```
document.body.innerHTML="";
var c=document.createElement("container")
c.innerHTML="<div>"
while(c.firstChild)document.body.appendChild(c.firstChild);
alert(document.body.innerHTML)


when you send the "<div>" , it will be auto fixed to a full element in the dom tree immediately. 

later you send "</div>" will take no effect
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I was struggling with. After some thought I finally got to a viable solution